# How do I write a string equation solver in python?

Tags: python, equation, algebra, solver

Thanks in advance! 
I am writing a program to check if `a` is true and then return True or False. I need to split it up at the equal sign and then check if the 1st item in the list is equal to the second item and vise-versa. Here is what I have so far:

```
def s_equation(a):
    equal=a.split("=")
```

Comment: homework? Give an example of the kinds of equations you want to "solve".

Comment: the algebra tag implies you need to handle variables, not just constants and operators.  is this true?  what kinds of operators do you need to support?

Comment: as many as possible. I also want multi operation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use eval() to evaluate each part of the equation:

```
def s_equation(a):
    left, right = a.split('=')
    return eval(left) == eval(right)
```

Some tests:

```
>>> s_equation('1+1+1=3')
True
>>> s_equation('2*2=8')
False
```

Answer (score 4):

```
left, right = a.split("=")
assert left == right
```

---

You're gonna need to give us more details than that if you want a useful answer. Are you trying to write a full computer algebra system (like e.g. Mathematica)? That's a biiiiig project and has already been done several times. Consider using something like [`Sage`](http://www.sagemath.org/).

Edit: math [beat me to the punch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135105/how-do-i-write-a-string-equation-solver-in-python/4135148#4135148), although I would recommend using [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) instead of `eval` unless you trust the input you will receive.

Comment: Ask a short question, get a short answer.

Comment: Not full like mathematica, though I am using the same algorithm as them.

Comment: @jmeyer10: it should work fine in all Pythons, though `literal_eval` is only in 2.6+. How about using Sage?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really give enough information to answer your question well. Do you want to test it as an identity (ie test the algebra) or as an instantaneous equality?

For the former, (install sympy first):

```
import sympy

def s_equation(a):
    x = sympy.Symbol('x')
    y = sympy.Symbol('y')
    left, right = a.split('=')
    return eval (left + '==' + right)
```

usage:

```
s_equation('x+x = x*2')
#True
s_equation('x+y**2 = y+x**2')
#False
```